# Complex numbers $z$ such that $|z|= 1$

Tags: complex-numbers

There are infinitely many complex numbers $z$ such that $|z|= 1$. Can anybody just explain this to me so I can get the picture.

Answer (score 12):

[image]

Here any $z$ on this circle satisfy $|z|=1$

Here $z=a+ib$  ie. $z=(a,b) $  and can be represented as a point or vector on complex plane above. $|z|^2=a^2+b^2 =1$. and this itself is a locus of a circle.

Comment: would you mind if I draw your graphic in TikZ ? yours look so much like paint.

Comment: @DominicMichaelis I would not mind but keep it simple as this one

Comment: ok made it, if i shall change anything tell me

Comment: fixed it even changed norm with absolute value

Comment: @DominicMichaelis Better than never. Thanx.

Answer (score 6):

Let $$z = a + ib$$

Now $$|z| = |a + ib|$$
$$ |z|^2 = a^2+b^2$$
$$ |z| = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$$

Hence given equation becomes, $$a^2 + b^2 = 1$$

which is the **equation of a circle**. Hence there are **infinitely many points** on this unit circle which satisfy the given equation.

Comment: Thanks that makes things clear.

Comment: Just a small point, $|z|^2 = a^2 + b^2$, not $|z|$.

Answer (score 0):

There are not only infinitely many complex numbers on the unit circle, there are infinitely many Gaussian numbers (both real and imaginary parts being rational) there. For, take a Gaussian integer $z=m+ni$, both $m$ and $n$ being ordinary integers, and calculate $z/\bar z$, something that you should have done many times in high school. You see that the resulting complex number $x+iy$ has both $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb Q$, and of course its absolute value is $1$.